# Integrating X-editable and select2 (using Ajax to populate the options)

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, x-editable

Has anyone succeeded in getting [x-editable to work with select2](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select2), using ajax?

I have succeeded in populating the autocomplete using an ajax request, but when the user selects an option, the x-editable link reads "empty" onblur.

My code is as follows:

```
<a id='elem' data-type='select2'></a>
<script>
  $('#elem').editable({
    select2: {
      placeholder:'provide a name',
      allowClear: true,
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      query: function(query){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/usage/users',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            full_name: query.term,
            select: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name']
          }
        }).done(function(data){
          results = []
          for (i in data)
            results.push({
              text: data[i].full_name,
              id: data[i].id
            });
          query.callback({results:results});
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```